# Why is CodeIgniter adding an extra asterisk to this query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following code, and I cannot figure out why CodeIgniter is adding an additional wildcard to the query it generates.

**Code**

```
class Foo_Model extends CI_Model {
  private $table = 'foo';

  public function get_all_foos() {
    $table = $this->table;   
    $this->db->select("$table.*")->from($table);
    return $this->get()->result();
  }
}
```

And I get the following Error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL >server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM (`foo`, `foo`)' at line 1
>
> SELECT `foo`.*, * FROM (`foo`, `foo`)

Why is there query generating incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried this query without the method chaining? Have you also tried not assigning the class property `$table` to a local variable but actually just referencing `$this->$table` in the from clause? The fact that it shows two table references in the from clause is definitely odd. However as Catfish mentioned, the `select()` method is not really needed here if you are selecting all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select everything, don't use the `->select()` statement. This should be equivalent to what your expected.

```
class Foo_Model extends CI_Model {
  private $table = 'foo';

  public function get_all_foos() {
    $table = $this->table;   
    $this->db->from($table);
    return $this->get()->result();
  }
}
```

See `$this->db->get` from the documentation for an example - http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of Codeigniter 2.1.2

This should work for you:

```
$this->db->select("`$table`.*",false)->from($table);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select everything, the fastest way to do it is by using `get()` directly with table name.
 for example:

```
class Foo_Model extends CI_Model {
  private $table = 'foo';

  public function get_all_foos() {
   $table = $this->table;
   return $this->db->get($table)->result();
  }
}
```